Why "לֹא יִהְיֶה לְךָ אֱלֹהִים אֲחֵרִים" uses singular יִהְיֶה?
Regarding singular יהיה in "לֹא יִהְיֶה לְךָ אֱלֹהִים אֲחֵרִים" in both versions of the Ten COmmandments.
Does it mean that "אלוהים אחרים" is singular as in "כִּי מִי־גוֹי גָּדוֹל אֲשֶׁר־לוֹ אֱלֹהִים קְרֹבִים אֵלָיו כַּיהוָה אֱלֹהֵינוּ ..." or "אלוהים אחרים" is plural and there's a particular reason to use single יהיה?
I've searched the Torah and found plenty of examples of plural יהיו and no examples of יהיה with plural subject (maybe I've missed some?).

What about Gen 12:16 and 32:6?

It's common for the verb that precedes its subject to not agree. See eg Num 9:6 and many many more.

@magicker72 Both use singular צאן or שור. In Hebrew, we say "היה לי כדור ומקל", not "היו לי כדור ומקל".

Speculation here, so comment instead of answer. If it have been written plural, one might think that having multiple others is prohibited, but having only one is permitted. So this should be read as לא יהיה לך [אף אחד מכל] אלהים אחרים.

@AlBerko You can't bring proof from modern Hebrew. In any case, the subject צאן ובקר is plural. If you're excluding that case from your question, you should explain why.
